# Probability of P(X = Y) with Poisson and Geometric distributions

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

Random independent variables X and Y have distributions of X ~ P(λ) (Poisson distribution) and Y ~ G(p) (geometric distribution), λ = 7.3, p = 0.6. Find the probability P(X = Y).

Comment: You just want to evaluate that sum?  But taking out a factor of $\frac 1q$ it's basically $e^{\lambda q}$.

Comment: @lulu I have updated my post taking your suggestion into account, could you please check it out?

Comment: Looks good!  If you like, you can post your own solution below.  That way others can check your work and the cite can take the question off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$q = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4$$

$$P(X = k) = \frac{λ^k}{k!} ⋅ e^{-λ},  k = 0, 1, 2...$$

$$P(Y = k) = q^{k - 1}⋅p, k = 1, 2, 3...$$

$$P(X = Y) = P(X = Y = 1) + P(X = Y = 2) + {...}$$

$$P(X = Y) = P(X = 1)⋅P(Y=1) + P(X = 2)⋅P(Y=2) + {...}$$

$$P(X = Y) = \sum_{k = 1}^∞\frac{λ^k}{k!} ⋅ e^{-λ}⋅q^{k - 1}⋅p = e^{-λ}⋅p ⋅\sum_{k = 1}^∞\frac{λ^k}{k!}  ⋅q^{k - 1}$$

$$P(X = Y) = e^{-λ}⋅p ⋅\sum_{k = 1}^∞\frac{λ^k}{k!}  ⋅q^{k - 1} = e^{-λ}⋅p ⋅\frac{1}{q}⋅\sum_{k = 1}^∞\frac{(λq)^k}{k!}$$

$$P(X = Y) = e^{-λ}⋅p ⋅\frac{1}{q} ⋅ (\frac{λq}{1!} + \frac{(λq)^2}{2!} + \frac{(λq)^3}{3!} + {...})$$

$$P(X = Y) = e^{-λ}⋅p ⋅\frac{1}{q} ⋅ (e^{λq} - 1)$$

$$P(X = Y) = e^{-6.3}⋅0.6 ⋅\frac{1}{0.4} ⋅ (e^{6.3{⋅}0.4} - 1) ≈ 0.03148 $$

Thanks to @lulu for the help with this problem!

Comment: Now that you've posted an answer, maybe we do not need the identical calculation above, within your question?